# Inconsistencies with ADD CONSTRAINT index_name in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I created this example table

```
CREATE DATABASE foobar;
USE foobar;
CREATE TABLE foos (
  id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  bar_id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE bars (
  id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

Then ran this query

```
ALTER TABLE foos ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name FOREIGN KEY foreign_key_name(bar_id) REFERENCES bars(id);
```

Some mysql server will return this on `show create table foos`

```
CREATE TABLE `foos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `bar_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `constraint_name` (`bar_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `constraint_name` FOREIGN KEY (`bar_id`) REFERENCES `bars` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Then some other ones will return this on `show create table foos`

```
CREATE TABLE `foos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `bar_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `constraint_name` (`bar_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `foreign_key_name` FOREIGN KEY (`bar_id`) REFERENCES `bars` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Notice the differences in the index_name, it should be `foreign_key_name`.

At first I thought it was a problem between MySQL 5.5 vs 5.6, but that does not seem to be the case.

Does anyone know why sometimes the index_name is ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out after reading the documentations here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

When

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

then the `index_name` is ignored.

Comment: Please take the trouble to mark your own answer as correct, as this may help people with the same problem in future. No points I'm afraid (:-( ), but it will increase your karma (:-) )! I think that you have to wait 24 hours.

Comment: The answer implies that `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;` is a "flag" that can be set at the database level, and set "unknowingly," when it is actually scoped to the *connection* (session) level and is the default.  I also don't see where the answer is derived from the documentation cited.

Comment: @Vérace yes, waiting for time to expire so I can approve this.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I am removing that part of my answer to clear up the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

See if these sound close.  (Taken from Changelogs)

----- not yet released 5.7.6 Milestone 16 & 2015-02-02 5.6.23 -- Bugs Fixed -- InnoDB -----

An ALTER TABLE ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html ) operation that changed the name of a foreign key column resulted in a failure when reloading the foreign key constraint. The previous column name remained in the data dictionary cache instead of being evicted. (Bug #20031243)

----- 2014-02-10 MariaDB 10.0.8 -- -- -----

MDEV-4439 ALTER TABLE .. [ADD|DROP] FOREIGN KEY IF [NOT] EXISTS does not work if constraint name is not used. Patches for server and the Innodb engine. Server is fixed so it does nothing if no indexes left to alter. Innodb parser is fixed so it looks for the IF [NOT] EXISTS option in a string. Another change is that it uses the index name for the internal dictionary. Prior to that it only used the CONSTRAINT name for it.

----- 2009-07-13 5.1.37 -- Bugs Fixed -- -----

Renaming a column that appeared in a foreign key definition did not update the foreign key definition with the new column name. (Bug #21704)

----- 2008-01-29 5.1.23 -- Bugs Fixed -- -----

User-supplied names foreign key names might not be set to the right key, leading to foreign keys with no name. (Bug #30747)